# GLS with time series error

Tags: r, time-series

I have an issue with a model implying times series values (returns of indices etc...)
I'm regressing some returns over some others. Obviously I get a non homoskedastic var-cov error matrix. My data are weekly return (around 2000 obs)

I would like to weight my model. Remembering my econometrics classes, I get the var-covar errors  by doing

> res <-lm(w_return_indonesia_10y ~ w_return_jci)
>
> Omega <- res%*%t(res)

It didn't succeed to inverse it (probably non positive definite), so I used `ginv` function
to get a pseudo inverse. But it didn't work when I tried to sqrt it, I got NAN (wanted to do `Xnew <- X*1/sqrt(Omega)` ).

I've already tried few solutions:

the `gls` function:

```
gls( w_return_indonesia_10y ~ w_return_jci, correlation = corARMA(p=1, q=1))
```

This doesn't work, am I writing the code wrong, or is it too demanding ?

Also used:

```
arima(w_return_indonesia_10y, order =c(1,1,2), xreg = w_return_jci)
```

This works, but I don't get p-values (neither for `coef` nor for whole regression), don't get sum of squared, don't get `Fstat`, `tstat`, etc.

At the end I tried to implement my own `fgls` function, it worked, I got the estimates, but again I didn't obtain any information about sum of squares, p-values, etc.

I know there is also `fgls` in package `rfgls` to be used but I don't understand how to use it (there are probably other).

```
fgls(w_return_indonesia_10y ~ w_return_jci)
```

So far I have succeed to run a WLS (only keeping the diagonal of the var-cov and set in into "weight" in the lm function) and the GLS with `covAR1` which works.